# How to use a Tensorflow estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was following [this Tensorflow tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) on creating a Convolutional Neural Network.

I'm at the step where the training and test data is read:

```
def main(unused_argv):
  mnist = learn.datasets.load_dataset("mnist")
  train_data = mnist.train.images # Returns np.array
  train_labels = np.asarray(mnist.train.labels, dtype=np.int32)
  eval_data = mnist.test.images # Returns np.array
  eval_labels = np.asarray(mnist.test.labels, dtype=np.int32)
```

Up to here, everything is fine.

But then suddenly an estimator is created:

```
mnist_classifier = learn.Estimator(
      model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/mnist_convnet_model")
```

My questions are:

1. What is an Estimator?
2. The previous code doesn't save anything under `"/tmp/mnist_convnet_model"`. How come there is a model saved under that directory?
   How did it get there?

EDIT:

When I run the code, I get:

```
 Couldn't find trained model at ../tmp/mnist_convnet_model.
```

This is because the model isn't found under that directory structure.

How can I put the model there? Also, why do I have to put it there, instead of storing it in memory for the execution of the script.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is answered right there in the tutorial. Estimator is "a TensorFlow class for performing high-level model training, evaluation, and inference".

The answer to the second question is that no, nothing is saved to that directory yet. The estimator object will use this directory to save training checkpoints, logs etc. When you run this code the first time, it will not load anything. But once you train the model, it will load the saved state from there.

Comment: So when I run the code, I get `Couldn't find trained model at ../tmp/mnist_convnet_model.` because the model isn't found under that directory structure. How can I put the model there? Also, why do I have to put it there, instead of storing it in memory for the execution of the script.

Comment: If you don't want to reuse your trained model, you can just skip the model_dir argument, it is optional. Generally, the idea is that you have one piece of code that trains and saves the model and another that actually uses it to make predictions.

Comment: As for the error you are getting, I am not sure. Does this directory exist?